# How to use cognito refresh token to get new accessToken in flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito

I am currently using the Dart SDK `amazon-cognito-identity-dart-2` for authentication in flutter.

When a refresh token is generated for a session, how can I use this refresh token to get new jwt access token before expiration?. accessToken expires when app is running itself. Only in login and signup ,i can fetch refresh token, but i want to get new accesstoken in main function when old one expires. Can anyone answer to this.

Comment: In general, you should save your refresh token somewhere securely. Then whenever you want to access some resource, you get an access token from refresh token.

Comment: I'm not getting it .can you help me out by explaining it in detail.because i saved refresh token using shared preference and i tried calling it but it didn't work. please